# PostgreSQL database online viewer

Tags: postgresql, viewer

Could you please suggest any PostgreSQL database online viewer/manager? Can't find anything decent besides desktop pgAdmin.

(The database is hosted at Heroku/Amazon)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: phpPgAdmin?
http://phppgadmin.sourceforge.net/doku.php
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-deploy-php-to-heroku-in-seconds--net-27657

Comment: What exactly is an "online viewer"? This might help: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Community_Guide_to_PostgreSQL_GUI_Tools

Comment: I mean a website where I can sign up, add my database connection specifying the host/database/user name and password, port number, etc. , connect to my database and see the database's tables and data in my browser.

Comment: So, you want something like MS Access in a web page, based on PostgreSQL?